# ERRAI Tutorial (3.1.1) error during deployment on Wildfly server

Tags: gwt, wildfly-8, errai

I am running the stock Errai-Tutorial (3.1.1) in Eclipse using Maven 3.2.1.  It runs fine in SuperDev mode, but when I try to deploy it using 'clean package wildfly:deploy', everything compiles fine but I get an error during deployment (with the Debug flag set):

```
[INFO] <<< wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ errai-tutorial <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ errai-tutorial ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=130, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=53, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=1, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=109, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=84, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=2}
[DEBUG] org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.2.Final:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.13.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.13.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.13.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.13.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.3.0:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0:compile
[DEBUG]                org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.10:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jboss.jdf:stacks-client:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.10:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.2.GA:compile
[DEBUG]    org.wildfly:wildfly-cli:jar:8.1.0.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.aesh:aesh:jar:0.33.11:compile
[DEBUG]          org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:jar:1.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss:staxmapper:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.wildfly.security:wildfly-security-manager:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.sasl:jboss-sasl:jar:1.0.4.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.remoting:jboss-remoting:jar:4.0.3.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.remotingjmx:remoting-jmx:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[DEBUG]          org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling:jar:1.4.2.Final:compile
[DEBUG]          org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling-river:jar:1.4.2.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss:jboss-vfs:jar:3.2.5.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       sun.jdk:jconsole:jar:jdk:system
[DEBUG]       org.wildfly:wildfly-build-config:jar:8.1.0.Final:compile
[DEBUG]    org.wildfly:wildfly-controller-client:jar:8.1.0.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss:jboss-dmr:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.threads:jboss-threads:jar:2.1.1.Final:compile
[DEBUG]    org.wildfly:wildfly-protocol:jar:8.1.0.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.2.2.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.2.2.Final:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.13.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.3.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.10
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.jdf:stacks-client:jar:1.0.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.10
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.2.GA
[DEBUG]   Included: org.wildfly:wildfly-cli:jar:8.1.0.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.aesh:aesh:jar:0.33.11
[DEBUG]   Included: org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:jar:1.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss:staxmapper:jar:1.1.0.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.wildfly.security:wildfly-security-manager:jar:1.0.0.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.sasl:jboss-sasl:jar:1.0.4.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.remoting:jboss-remoting:jar:4.0.3.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.remotingjmx:remoting-jmx:jar:2.0.0.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling:jar:1.4.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling-river:jar:1.4.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss:jboss-vfs:jar:3.2.5.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: sun.jdk:jconsole:jar:jdk
[DEBUG]   Included: org.wildfly:wildfly-build-config:jar:8.1.0.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.wildfly:wildfly-controller-client:jar:8.1.0.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss:jboss-dmr:jar:1.2.0.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.threads:jboss-threads:jar:2.1.1.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.wildfly:wildfly-protocol:jar:8.1.0.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.2.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.2.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.13.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.13.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.13.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.3.0
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.5
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@21a722ef]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) checkPackaging = true
[DEBUG]   (f) force = true
[DEBUG]   (f) hostname = localhost
[DEBUG]   (f) port = 9990
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: org.jboss.errai.demo:errai-tutorial:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/steve/Documents/eclipse_workspace/errai-tutorial-master/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) settings = org.apache.maven.execution.SettingsAdapter@253217dd
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) targetDir = /Users/steve/Documents/eclipse_workspace/errai-tutorial-master/target
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] No <id> element was found in the POM - Getting credentials from CLI entry
Feb 21, 2015 5:20:36 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.2.Final
Feb 21, 2015 5:20:37 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.2.Final
Feb 21, 2015 5:20:37 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.3.Final
[DEBUG] Executing deployment
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:40 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-21T17:20:37-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 50M/710M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project errai-tutorial: Deployment failed and was rolled back. "java.io.IOException: No such file or directory" -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project errai-tutorial: Deployment failed and was rolled back.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.wildfly.plugin.common.DeploymentExecutionException: Deployment failed and was rolled back.
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.execute(StandaloneDeployment.java:180)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.executeDeployment(AbstractDeployment.java:121)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.doExecute(AbstractDeployment.java:146)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractAppDeployment.doExecute(AbstractAppDeployment.java:70)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.AbstractDeployment.execute(AbstractDeployment.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: "java.io.IOException: No such file or directory"
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getActionResult(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getResultFromNode(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:123)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:42)
    at org.wildfly.plugin.deployment.standalone.StandaloneDeployment.execute(StandaloneDeployment.java:169)
    ... 25 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The only other error I see during compilation is the following (but this does not seem to impact SuperDev mode, so it is probably just a warning):

```
[INFO] ERROR [Ejb3Configuration] HHH000050: Container is providing a null PersistenceUnitRootUrl: discovery impossible
[INFO] WARN [ConnectionProviderInitiator] HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
```

Any ideas on why the deployment is failing?

Thanks,
Steve